# facebook style image resize java

Tags: java, facebook, image-processing

Is there a java library that I can use to resize user uploaded images the way its done on facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple options. Recently I used [java-image-scaling](https://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/) and it works fine. Also `java.awt` has `Image.getScaledInstance(..)` and I guess [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) also has such options.

Answer (score 0):

There's a java library called [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) (Java Advanced Imaging). [Here](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/java/how-to-resize-uploaded-images-using-java-better-way.html)'s an example of doing Image resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Aurigma](http://www.aurigma.com/). This is the Java plugin that Facebook used until recently; now I think they roll their own.